# Can anyone explain this program?

Tags: c

```
int array[2][2] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
int i;
int sum = 0;

for (i =0; i < 4; ++i)
{

    int x, y;

    x = i % 2;

    if (x)
    {
        y = 0;
        }
    else
    {
        y = 1;
        }
    sum += array[x][y];
}

printf("%d\n", sum);
```

Comment: No.  Can't explain it.  What do **you** think it might do?  You could update your question with **your** understanding.  We might be able to comment on that.

Comment: What are your initial thoughts?  Add them to your question so people know where to start helping you out.

Comment: Run it, and print out the values of `i`, `x`, `y`, and `sum` for each iteration in the loop?

Comment: Actually it won't compile. `Else` in not valid in C/C++ and even C#.

Comment: if we're talking about code that compiles, then even replacing `Else` with `else` won't do the job.

Comment: It won't compile because there are statements outside of any function. Please post only code that you have compiled and run -- to do otherwise is a rude waste of people's time.

Comment: @Krish ignoring the comments and answer won't help you much... I saw you edited and fixed the `Else` but please respond to the other people if you really want help on this.

Comment: Ask your teacher for a program that compiles. Can't explain something that doesn't work. http://codepad.org/7ciDQ378

Comment: @Krish,`if(x)`? I think you meant `if(x==0)`. I would suggest thst your trace the program on paper.

Answer (score 4):

It's short enough that you could walk through it yourself (since this is homework) and run each line yourself on paper.  If there is any line that you can't figure out, ask a more specific question.  Just use pencil, make a box to show the values of x, y, i, sum and all 4 elements of the array.  Then walk through changing the values in those boxes as you examine lines of code and you will see exactly what's happening.  One thing you should know is that "if (x)" will  treat x as true when it is 1.